# Moving from no layers to layered costmaps

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, costmap-2d, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i did all the setting up to get my robot working with navigation 2D in ROS Fuerte. After that, I went to ROS Hydro and got it to work again. My problem is now I want to change to layered costmaps, where the current map is in a layer (let's call it Obstacles) and the person i'm following is in another layer (let's call it PersonLayer). How can I do that? Is there a more easy to understand and/or complete tutorial than the ones in the costmap_2d section of the wiki? I'm having some trouble in understanding those.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200831/moving-from-no-layers-to-layered-costmaps/) by [RodrigoLG](https://answers.ros.org/users/20409/rodrigolg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Hydro automatically converts your old configuration to use layers. After you start navigation, look at the costmap parameter space to see which layers are being used.

Do you have a specific question about the tutorials?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1